# When can you apply the principle of indifference?

Tags: probability

If someone wanted to assign the probability of a dice landing on 1, there seems to be ample reason to give it a probability of 1/6.

However, imagine a scenario where we randomly pick a human being, stop him in its tracks, and measure whichever direction out of 360 degrees he happens to be facing towards.

In this case, if we have no prior knowledge of where a person might be facing towards, would the probability of his particular direction be 1 out of 360 or not?

Comment: This belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave when will people like you understand that statistics was originally a philosophy and these kinds of questions that hint at whether one should apply the principle of indifference or not is part of philosophy. This isn’t a standardized stats question.

Comment: Orignally, sure.  But not now.  Nor is this specific question on topic for this site.   Have you read the help site? https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Again, this is not a stats question. Try asking a stats professor this question and he’ll tell you to stop wasting his time

Comment: One of the things that could bias the result is that many American cities are laid out in a rectangular grid configuration with north-south avenues and east-west streets. So drivers and pedestrians there are likely to be facing in one of the cardinal directions.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some trends which bias the probability ever so slightly, like when Muslims pray facing Mecca. However, overall, the principle of indifference would apply in the same way that it does to the dice. We don't have enough information to assume any particular direction the person is facing, and thus we can treat it as a uniform probability distribution. So then, of course, if we are choosing between 360 options, and there's no bias, the probability of each one being selected is 1/360. So yes, the probability of the person's particular direction being any particular given integer between 0 and 360 would be 1/360 and the principle of indifference applies.

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two technicalities you would need to address if you were to take the idea seriously. You would need to define a baseline for your measurement of direction, and a protocol for determining, to the nearest degree, which direction person was facing, given that their head might be pointing in one direction, their sternum in another, they might be pointing upwards, etc etc.

Leaving that aside, the answer depends on your sample. Human motion is not random. If you pick from shoppers on Oxford Street, there might be a bias in favour of pointing in directions parallel to the pavement. If you pick people at random out of the frenzied crowd at one of my book launches, they are likely to be found pointing in the direction of the door. Etc etc.

Comment: *"You would need to define a baseline for your measurement of direction, and a protocol for determining, to the nearest degree, which direction person was facing, given that their head might be pointing in one direction, their sternum in another, they might be pointing upwards, etc etc."* << Just a few weeks ago I talked with someone who had developed a smartphone app so you can film yourself jogging and the app will tell you how each part of your body is oriented and give you advice to jog better (whatever that means).